# Running a project in QT Creator in Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, qt-creator

I want to develop a video player using FFMPEG in QT Creator on Windows, but completely new to QT Creator environment.

I have downloaded a sample project from this [link](https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV). When I opened in it QT Creator and ran it, it returned this error, `:-1: error: avutil is required, but compiler can not find it`.

I have downloaded this (ffmpeg-20130322-git-e0e8c20-win64-static) FFMPEG file and extracted it to a folder in C partition. I think I get that error since QT cannot find where the FFMPEG is, but still don't know how to link it. Could you please kindly help me to solve this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set some environment vars so that compiler can find FFmpeg and other libraries files.

For VC compiler, they are INCLUDE and LIB. For gcc, they are CPATH and LIBRARY_PATH. e.g.

vc:

```
set INCLUDE=ffmpeg_path\include;portaudio_path\include;%INCLUDE%
set LIB=ffmpeg_path\lib;portaudio_path\lib;%LIB%
```

gcc in unix shell environment(including mingw with sh.exe):

```
export CPATH=ffmpeg_path/include:portaudio_path/include:$CPATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=ffmpeg_path/include:portaudio_path/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

gcc in windows cmd environment without sh.exe

```
set CPATH=ffmpeg_path\include;portaudio_path\include;%CPATH%
set LIBRARY_PATH=ffmpeg_path\lib;portaudio_path\lib;%LIBRARY_PATH%
```

If you are building in QtCreator, goto QtCreator's 'Projects' page and add or append those environment.

I think i should write some documents to show how to build QtAV.

Comment: LucasWang, Thanks a lot for the answer. But, now I get many OpenGL related error messages like this, "C:\QtAV-master\QtAV-master\src\GLWidgetRenderer.cpp(100) : error C2065: 'GL_SMOOTH' : undeclared identifier". I think linking to OpenGL is missing, but cannot figure out how to link it.

Answer (score 3):

i am the author of QtAV.
I guess you are using the official Qt5 library which is built against OpenGL ES2. But QtAV use OpenGL 1.x. So you may get compile error. But I have fixed this some days ago by disabling OpenGL code. So i am wondering whether you are using the latest code. If not, please use

```
git update
```

to update QtAV. If compile error still exists, please let me know. I tested on my computer and works fine.
You can also disable OpenGL code by modifying QtAV.pro. Just delete 'gl' here

```
OptionalDepends = portaudio direct2d gdiplus xv gl #openal
```

I'm not familiar with OpenGL, so support for OpenGL ES2 will take some days. If you want enable OpenGL, you can use Qt4.8 or build Qt5 yourself.
I suggest you to use Qt4.8 because Qt5 is not stable now.

: )

Answer (score 0):

After some research I was able to solve the above issue. Here is the solution,

- Download "ffmpeg-20130322-git-e0e8c20-win32-dev" from this [link](http://beatinginfinity.blogspot.tw/2013/04/running-qtav-project-using-qt5-ffmpeg.html).
- Copy all the folders inside "ffmpeg-20130322-git-e0e8c20-win32-dev/include" folder to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include"
- Copy all the DLL files from "ffmpeg-20130322-git-e0e8c20-win32-dev/lib" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib"

But now there are many errors related to OpenGL commands. Finally, I was able to successfully run the project. [This](http://beatinginfinity.blogspot.tw/2013/04/running-qtav-project-using-qt5-ffmpeg.html) article on my blog shows the steps.